# How are resistivity and tunneling related?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, electrical-resistance, electronics, quantum-tunneling

If we consider a sandwich with three nanometric layers: conductor-insulator-conductor and apply voltage (lower than breakdown voltage) from both sides tunneling will occur. Is tunneling dependent on resistivity of the insulator? Intuitively one can think that tunneling would be lower in good insulators, but is it really that simple?

Comment: Maybe this could help ? [Josephson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's quite that simple. The resistivity may be related to the **barrier potential energy** separating the two reservoirs, which directly modulates tunneling in the obvious way (higher energy = less tunneling). But there is one barrier which classically you'd describe with an infinite resistance (a Dirac $\delta$-function potential) which admits tunneling just fine because it's also infinitesimally thin.

Answer (score 0):

Resistivity is a measure of the band gap of the insulator and its density. For tunneling to have a possibility to happen one energy level from the left side of the sandwich must match with another energy level from the right side of the sandwich. The conclusion is that resistivity doesn't affect tunnelling.